# Product attribute empty value from order item in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, orders

[image]I know that there are a lot of questions already for that matter but im not able to figure out how to get a custom product attribute from an woocommerce order. here is what i have try:

```
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_data = $order->get_data();

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values) {

    $product = $item_values->get_product(); // Get the product
    $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); // the Product id
    $tokens = get_post_meta($product_id, 'Tokens', true);
    }
```

I have also try:

```
    $tokens = $product->get_attribute( 'Tokens' );
```

and

```
    $tokens = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, 'Tokens', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
```

My custom product attribute has the name "**Tokens**" and the value **5000** but im getting an empty return,

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: That can happen for a variable product when the product attribute is not set as an attribute for variations. When you have a product variation from this parent variable product as order item, you can't get the anything from the product variation itself and you need to get the parent variable product, to get your product attribute value.

Comment: @LoicTheAztecso what i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen for a **variable product** when the product attribute **is not set as an attribute for variations**.

So when you have **a product variation as order item**, you need to get the **parent variable product** to get your product attribute value *(if this product attribute is not set as an attribute for variations)*.

If it is the case for "Tokens" product attribute, try the following:

```
$attribute = 'Tokens';
$order     = wc_get_order( 857 );

// Loop through order line items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object

    // For Product Variation type
    if( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ){
        $parent = wc_get_product($product->get_parent_id());
        $term_names = $parent->get_attribute($attribute);
    }
    // For other Product types
    else {
        $term_names = $product->get_attribute($attribute);
    }

    // Testing display (the string of coma separated term names if many)
    if( ! empty( $term_name ) )
        echo '<p>'.$term_name.'</p>';
}
```

Tested and works in Woocommerce 3+